# PowerPoint charts events right click and double click don't get fired

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am doing some working on a PowerPoint add-in. I have to do some additional work like showing an extra menu or creating a checkbox when user right clicks on the slide. I am doing this like

```
    PowerPoint.Application pApp = this.Application;    
    pApp.WindowBeforeRightClick += pApp_WindowBeforeRightClick;
```

But this event doesn't get fired. I tried debugging but this event never gets listened. Same is the case with the double click event. Am I declaring this wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code or declaration. Its a bug in PowerPoint that Microsoft has not yet fixed since PowerPoint 2007.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745746%28v=office.15%29.aspx) the double click event gets fired on 3 views but in reality it only gets fired in the slide sorter view. Only the `OnWindowSelection` events gets fired in PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll have to find another way then.